# Как запустить код discord-бота на токен обычного человека?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, token

Я пишу бота на фреймворке discord.py - disnake, но из-за популярности первого решение проблемы на дискордпае я тоже пойму. Так вот: я подумал, а что если запустить код от бота на токен обычного юзера? Я раздобыл токен своего второго аккаунта и вбил его в bot.run() вместо токена бота, но в консоли всплыла вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\http.py", line 467, in static_login
    data: user.User = await self.request(Route("GET", "/users/@me"))
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\http.py", line 420, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
disnake.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\кодинг\путхон\randombot\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    bot.run("токен юзера")
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 856, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 835, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 798, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 658, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token.strip())
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\http.py", line 471, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure("Improper token has been passed.") from exc
disnake.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000226F80025F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Вопрос: что означает эта ошибкка и как её исправить? И вообще возможно ли запустить код бота на токен юзера? Заранее спасибо.
Вот если что код самого бота:

```
import disnake, time, requests, math
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.enums import ButtonStyle
import random as randomy
from threading import Thread

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
intents=disnake.Intents.all()
bot.remove_command("help") #удаление команды

@bot.event #подготовка бота
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Бот {bot.user} запущен!")
    await bot.change_presence(status=disnake.Status.idle, activity=disnake.Game("$help"))#статус

def getcrypto():
    response = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
    response_json = response.json()
    return float(response_json["RUB"]["last"])


@bot.command()
async def price_crypto(ctx):
    cryptopr1 = getcrypto()
    cryptopr2 = str(cryptopr1)
    cryptopr2 = cryptopr2[:6]
    cryptopr2 = float(cryptopr2)
    cryptopr2 = math.ceil(cryptopr2)
    embed = disnake.Embed(title='Цена криптовалюты:', description = int(cryptopr2))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    print(cryptopr1)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('?work')

#@bot.command()
#async def buycrypto(ctx, *, args):
    

bot.run("токен")
```

Comment: ```isnake.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков И как это решить? токен верный, я перепроверил

Comment: А если немного включить логику? если вы использовали токен, и он точно верный, не может ли это означать что токен пользователя и бота разные вещи?... кажись я глупость сморозил да?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков хорошо, спасибо что вразумили меня.

Comment: Селф-боты запрещены у Дискорда. Вам обычного бота мало?